# Use Entity Framework to update column length and data in single migration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using Entity Framework with code first migrations. I need to increase the length of a `VARCHAR(50)` column to `VARCHAR(100)` and update all the records in that column by doubling the string. So "abc" turns into "abcabc" (except the values will be longer than three characters).

It would be nice to be able to do this in a single code first migration but I'm having trouble getting it working. I first tried using this code:

```
AlterColumn("dbo.SomeTable", "SomeField", c => c.String(maxLength: 100, unicode: false));

using (TheEntityContext ctx = new TheEntityContext())
{
    foreach (Entities.SomeTable st in ctx.SomeTables)
        st.SomeField = st.SomeField + st.SomeField;

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

but I got this error:

> The model backing the 'TheEntityContext' context has changed since
>   the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to
>   update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

I thought gee that's weird. Maybe I can't use Entity Framework inside a code first migration? So I tried this code:

```
AlterColumn("dbo.SomeTable", "SomeField", c => c.String(maxLength: 100, unicode: false));

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    conn.Open();
    string sql = "UPDATE SomeTable SET SomeField = SomeField + '' + SomeField";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

but I got this error:

> String or binary data would be truncated.

Then I though is the `ALTER TABLE` statement to make the field longer not taking effect before the `UPDATE` statement runs? So I changed the `UDPDATE` statement to be a 50 character string and it ran fine. Running `Update-Database -Verbose` also indicates that it's not running the `ALTER TABLE` statement before the `UPDATE` statement.

So what's the deal here? Do I have to run the `ALTER TABLE` in one migration then the code to update the table in another?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The point is that EF executes migrations as part of a transaction.

You open a new transaction inside up, which is not necessary, simply use

```
AlterColumn("dbo.SomeTable", "SomeField", c => c.String(maxLength: 100, unicode: false));

Sql("UPDATE dbo.SomeTable SET SomeField = '' + SomeField + SomeField");
```

In this case the `Sql()` function would run in the same transaction context and the error should not appear.

**EDIT**: clarification on transaction context of `Sql()` function.

Comment: So when you use the Sql function is runs in its own transaction? When you say it's not necessary, what do you mean?

Comment: no, what I meant was that the alter table statement is running inside a transaction. If you use the Sql() function, it's executed in the same transaction scope. If you open a new SqlConnection, it will use a separate transaction context. I will update the answer to clarify this.

Comment: I see, so you have to run both statements inside the same transaction and I was creating a new one that didn't know about the fact that the other one increased the field size. So is it possible to get ahold of the transaction that is implicitly created for the migration and pass it into the database context? For reasons I did not disclose in my question that would be preferable to using the Sql() function.

Comment: uh, yes, just use "Sql()". It's provided by EF exactly for this purpose, please review https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh829520.aspx for details.

Comment: It happened that for me I had generated an earlier migration which was not applied. All I needed to do was change the max length to a different value for the migration to work

Comment: This is what I usually do as well. Create some kind of "dummy" transaction to force a change (the same we did when we were working with SQL directly :))